# Flutter get source URL along with Text shared from web page

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am new to Flutter. I want to get the text along with its source. Currently, I am using **receive_sharing_intent** which is serving the purpose of TextStream and Url individually.
I want to share the copied text from the browser and keep its URL along with it.

I followed [this](https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent) doc hence my **main.dart** is same as:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:receive_sharing_intent/receive_sharing_intent.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  StreamSubscription _intentDataStreamSubscription;
  List<SharedMediaFile> _sharedFiles;
  String _sharedText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // For sharing or opening urls/text coming from outside the app while the app is in the memory
    _intentDataStreamSubscription =
        ReceiveSharingIntent.getTextStream().listen((String value) {
      setState(() {
        _sharedText = value;
      });
    }, onError: (err) {
      print("getLinkStream error: $err");
    });

    // For sharing or opening urls/text coming from outside the app while the app is closed
    ReceiveSharingIntent.getInitialText().then((String value) {
      setState(() {
        _sharedText = value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _intentDataStreamSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const textStyleBold = const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Shared files:", style: textStyleBold),
              Text(_sharedFiles?.map((f)=> f.path)?.join(",") ?? ""),
              SizedBox(height: 100),
              Text("Shared urls/text:", style: textStyleBold),
              Text(_sharedText ?? "")
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed to this or any Reference will work.
Thanks!!

Comment: Could you provide more details on what you're trying to achieve? What have done so far and issues that you encountered. Code snippets and screenshots would help.

Comment: @Omatt Sure, I've updated the question.